DropDownFormField keeps its old value
When using a DropdownButtonFormField instead of a DropdownButton, the selectedValue given is not taken into account when rebuilding the widget. When can I do to circumvent this ?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: HomeRoute(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomeRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeRoute({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeRoute> createState() => _HomeRouteState();
}

class _HomeRouteState extends State<HomeRoute> {
  String selectedValue = '1';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Building with selected value : $selectedValue');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Title'),),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
            value: selectedValue,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                // Not updating the value
                // selectedValue = value!;
              });
            },
            items: [
              for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: '$i', child: Text('$i'),),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Stackoverflow tells me that I need to add more details, but there's nothing more to be said.

No, it isn't. Try it.

Try below code hope its help to you Using DropdownButton
DropdownButton<String>(
        value: selectedValue,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            selectedValue = value!;
          });
        },
        items: [
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: '$i',
              child: Text('$i'),
            ),
        ],
      ),

Using DropdownButtonFormField
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
              value: selectedValue,
              onChanged: (value) {
//               setState(() {
//                 selectedValue = value!;
//               });
              },
              items: [
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                  DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: '$i',
                    child: Text('$i'),
                  ),
              ],
            ),

Result before selection: 
Result after selection: 
DropdownButton: It doesn't maintain any state related to the selected value. If you want to update the selected value of a DropdownButton, you need to manage the state, using a StatefulWidget or a state management.
DropdownButtonFormField: This means it automatically manages the state of the selected value. When you select an item from the dropdown, the form field value is automatically updated.

I need a DropdownButtonFormField, hence why I mentionned having tried with a DropdownButton in the question itself.

You do not understand the question. I want the value showned by DropdownButtonFormField to reflect selectedValue even if selectedValue is not set to the value given by the onChanged callback. Your answer does not achieve that.

Found a workaround to force the DropdownButtonFormField to update its internal index value by calling didUpdateWidget :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: HomeRoute(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomeRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeRoute({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeRoute> createState() => _HomeRouteState();
}

class _HomeRouteState extends State<HomeRoute> {
  String selectedValue = '1';
  GlobalKey<State> dropdownButtonFormFieldKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Building with selected value : $selectedValue');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Title'),),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
            key: dropdownButtonFormFieldKey,
            value: selectedValue,
            onChanged: (value) async {
              setState(() {
                // Not updating the value
                // selectedValue = value!;
              });
              dropdownButtonFormFieldKey.currentState?.didUpdateWidget(DropdownButtonFormField<String>(items: [], onChanged: (_) {},));
              dropdownButtonFormFieldKey.currentState?.setState(() {});
            },
            items: [
              for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: '$i', child: Text('$i'),),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Of course this makes the code quite horrendous to look at, but it works and seemingly without side-effects as didUpdateWidget doesn't do much other then update the index.
